# What happened if Mordin died in Mass effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Seeing the precedent questions about genophage and mordin, I was wondering what happened in the (very unlikely) case you let mordin died in Mass effect 2.

What are the (mass) effects on the genophage issue, on eve survival and about War assets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-/62188663), nothing really changes:

> You really do get Not-Mordin. Another Salarian, I forget his name but Joker makes a joke by calling him Not-Mordin. Mordin happened to be the only person not to live in my file at the end of Mass Effect 2.
>
> He plays the same role Mordin would but it's not as meaningful to the player.

The new character's name is [Padok Wiks](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Padok_Wiks).  Like the above post, that wiki says that he can replace Mordin as well, and is the Salarian STG base commander on Sur'Kesh.  You meet him during Priority: Sur'Kesh, as LessPop_MoreFizz notes below.

Comment: You'll meet Wiks during the mission **Priority:Sur'Kesh**, regardless of whether Mordin is alive. He's kind of boring.

Comment: Thanks to your intel I discovered the characters, and I watch some cutscene videos on youtube. And as [you can see](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxDivMHb0EE), he is not that boring in the end: he even punched mordin once upon a time! ^^